# 'It is, isn't it' OR 'it is, is it not?'

Tags: word-usage, british-english, questions

My girlfriend and I are having an argument about whether these two phrases mean the same thing:

'It is, isn't it'

'It is, is it not?'

I argue that the first is affirmative. Meaning that it would be used after a person gives an opinion. Whereas the other desires an opinion from somebody else.

She argues that they mean the same thing and can be used interchangeably.

As my example I use this conversation:

Person 1 - "Fine weather today"

Person 2 - "It is, isn't it" (in my opinion this works)

If you try to use the the other statement, it doesn't feel right to me because it seems like the statement is asking for a repetition of the original opinion.

Person 1 - "Fine weather today"

Person 2 - "It is, is it not?" (This is an open question, so person 1 would be left feeling as though they would have to respond with their opinion again)

My question is whether they are both grammatically correct, whether they mean the same thing and also which is preferable/most usable?

Comment: With nothing but my own gut feeling to back me up, I agree with you. The uncontracted tag question is much, much less likely to be used rhetorically. Of course, even the contracted version is usually only rhetoric in repetitive tags where the tag verb is the same as the main verb; in “You bought a house, didn't you?”, a response is expected whether you contract or not.

Comment: Not sure, why the question was closed as unclear. Both answerers and commenter understood the question and answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is not it?" ("Isn't it?") and "Is it not?" mean exactly the same thing and they are both grammatical. Consider:

> Is not this your umbrella?

and

> Is this not your umbrella?

Nothing wrong or ungrammatical with either, although we are more likely to say:

> Isn't this your umbrella?

Strangely, saying "Is not it?" sounds very awkward and stiff, and yet we say "Isn't it?" all the time without giving it a moment's thought.

Comment: *Is not it* is more than awkward and stiff. It's not grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct, but the second seems less typical for American English, which typically uses contractions in tag questions. but the intonation will help decide whether or not the [tag question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question) is rhetorical. The [Intonation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question#Intonation) section in the Wikipedia article linked above will explain the intonation issue.

Here are two examples to contrast:

> He's dead, isn't he? (with falling intonation)

The above example shows resignation or perhaps fear on the part of the speaker that the pronoun referent is dead.

> He's dead, isn't he? (with rising intonation)

The second example makes it sound like the speaker is unsure (e.g. if asking about an elderly actor), or perhaps makes the speaker sound worried that the referent of "he" might actually not be dead (e.g. a zombie, or an attacker the speaker just fended off).

Say your questions out loud, with both intonations on each, and see what you think.

Comment: Interestingly, I don't think I've ever heard "is it not?" with a falling intonation. If I try it out for myself, it seems awkward. OTOH, "isn't it" works fine with both rising and falling intonations.